# Is there any edition of Oracle 11g for learning?

Tags: oracle11g

I want to learn new features of Oracle 11g and I think there is no basic edition available. I worked with Oracle 10g before but want to try out some advanced features on my home PC.

Is there any enterprise version available for learning but without time limit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free or trial Oracle database environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541844/free-or-trial-oracle-database-environment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can freely download any version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html), however there is no Oracle 11g Express yet. But you can download the full enterprise version if you wish

Comment: Read the license agreement. But basically you can use it "only for the purpose of developing, testing, prototyping and demonstrating your application, and not for any other purpose. ". There is no time limit.

Comment: IIRC, there is no time limit, you're simply restricted from using it for production purposes.  That said, it's a full-blown Oracle install, so you need real-world hardware for it.  I'd recommend against running this on a laptop or other low-spec machine.

Comment: @TWN: I want to install on desktop PC with 2 GB RAM. Is it not sufficient?

Comment: It depends what you're doing with it. It runs OK on my laptop with 4Gb. Well enough for development, certainly

Comment: @Paul: Few years back, I installed Oracle 9i Enterprise Edition on my laptop. The laptop got over-heated and burnt. I used to notice the CPU Fan making more sound when running such applications.

Comment: That's more a sign of a badly designed laptop. No application shold cause it to fail. And yes, it will hammer the CPU and disk, but it will work.

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle Database Express Edition 11g is now available:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 1):

At this time Oracle hasn't released an express edition of Oracle 11g.

Here is an article explaining the reasons:

http://news.techworld.com/applications/3203909/oracle-stalls-over-11g-express-release/

Since that article was written the first patch for 11gR2 has been released and there are rumors that 11g express may be available around Feb 2011.

Comment: But Express Edition won't include enterprise features. I want to learn advanced features.